# Calculating quantity based on lot size

Tags: elixir

I have this code and test:

```
  def order_quantity(:sell, free_quantity, lot_step_size, quantity_precision) do
    {q, _} = :erlang.float_to_binary(Float.floor(free_quantity / lot_step_size) * lot_step_size, decimals: quantity_precision) |> Float.parse()
    q
  end

assert order_quantity(:sell, 0.01977578, 0.00010000, 8) == 0.0197
assert order_quantity(:sell, 0.290709, 0.00100000, 8) == 0.29000000
assert order_quantity(:sell, 111.88800000, 0.01000000, 8) == 111.88
```

but I'm not happy with that -- is there a more Elixir-ish way to accomplish the same calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Float.floor/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Float.html#floor/2) is your friend here.

```elixir
iex|1▸ Float.floor 0.01977578, 4
0.0197
iex|2▸ Float.floor 0.290709, 3
0.29
iex|3▸ Float.floor 111.88800000, 2
111.88
```

Also, you’d probably better to rethink how you do pass `free_quantity`. It’d probably make more sense to pass it as an integer, rather than *not necessarily precise* float.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about precision, you should use the `:decimal` lib. https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.html

With this you can simply do:

```elixir
iex> Decimal.round("0.01977578", 4, :down)
#Decimal<0.0197>
```

where the first argument is either a float or a string, the second argument is the number of decimal places and the third argument is the rounding "mode".

Your main problem then is how to get the number of decimal places (an integer) from the `lot_step_size` float.

You could make a function that can calculate `places` from any given lot step size but if you know these only go to, say, 8 decimal places then you could write a more efficient (faster) "pattern" for each like this:

```elixir
  def places(0.00000001), do: 8
  def places(0.0000001), do: 7
  def places(0.000001), do: 6
  def places(0.00001), do: 5
  def places(0.0001), do: 4
  def places(0.001), do: 3
  def places(0.01), do: 2
  def places(0.1), do: 1

  def order_quantity(:sell, free_quantity, lot_step_size) do
    free_quantity
    |> to_string()
    |> Decimal.round(places(lot_step_size), :down)
    |> Decimal.to_float()
  end
```

Note that I cast back to float when I'm done but you would be better off using Decimal everywhere and avoiding floats.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin in this isolated case, that is true. But this is probably a microscopic part of a larger application that seems to be dealing with money. I strongly believe the developer should be at least using `:decimal` (or probably even https://github.com/kipcole9/money which uses `:decimal`).

Comment: Dealing with money definitely requires any native money implementation (kipcole9’s one is great, btw.) The issues are way wider than just rounding/decimals.